# Don't send filter if no values for ExtJS grid panel using remote filter (numeric vs. string fields)

Tags: javascript, extjs

ExtJS does not send a query in the request if you click the checkbox for filtering on a grid using a remote filter for *numeric* columns, however it sends a filter object with an empty value if you click on the filter box for any other type of value.

Here is an example of what is sent on a non-numeric request when you click the filter checkbox for a column and there is NO value in there yet (I've decoded the url for ease of reading):

`getData?_dc=1640804600546&start=0&page=1&limit=25&query=[{"operator":"like","property":"sleeveName"}]&node=root`

Here is what happens when you do the same thing, but for a numeric column:

`getData?_dc=1640804595175&page=1&start=0&limit=25&node=root`

As you can see, there is no `query` param sent at all in the second one, and this is the desired outcome for me for the first one if possible.

Comment: Are you using classic?  I noticed that in modern you can't click the filter checkbox until there is data entered in a query field.  Also on classic, if you delete the query string i till automatically uncheck the filter checkbox.

Comment: Yes, using classic. I wish that was the case, since the clearFilter function also doesn't work properly. It doesn't clear the value from the filter, it only unchecks the filter box. It also doesn't remove the style on the column header

Comment: Could you provide a working fiddle we can work with?